# PDF FontDescriptor Flags

Tags: pdf, winapi, mfc

How can I obtain the information about a TrueType font so I can fill the [PDF flags](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#G8.1914418) in an MFC application.

In my MFC application, I'm creating a PDF and trying to embed the fonts chosen by the user. I already have the [OUTLINETEXTMETRIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162755(v=vs.85).aspx)  struct of my font, but I still don't know how, for example, check if a font is *Serif, Symbolic or Script.*

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OUTLINETEXTMETRIC` has `otmTextMetrics` member, which shows Pitch and Family `tmPitchAndFamily`

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **lfPitchAndFamily**
>   Bits 4 through 7 of the member specify the font family and can be one
>   of the following values.
>
> ```
> FF_DECORATIVE
> FF_DONTCARE
> FF_MODERN
> FF_ROMAN
> FF_SCRIPT
> FF_SWISS
> ```

`lfPitchAndFamily` should AND with `0xF0` to get the family component:

```
String family;
OUTLINETEXTMETRIC otm = { sizeof(OUTLINETEXTMETRIC) };
if(GetOutlineTextMetrics(hdc, otm.otmSize, &otm))
{
    switch(otm.otmTextMetrics.tmPitchAndFamily & 0xF0)
    {
    case FF_ROMAN: family = "FF_ROMAN"; break;
    case FF_SWISS: family = "FF_SWISS"; break;
    case FF_MODERN: family = "FF_MODERN"; break;
    case FF_SCRIPT: family = "FF_SCRIPT"; break;
    case FF_DECORATIVE: family = "FF_DECORATIVE"; break;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
"Arial": FF_SWISS
"Times New Roman": FF_ROMAN
"Old English Text MT": FF_SCRIPT
```